# How to turn off 'Enhanced Tracking Protection' for Firefox browser via Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

My Selenium Java test script runs on Firefox browser.

Recently, it has started failing on applications where 'Enhanced Tracking Protection' is turned on.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enhanced-tracking-protection-firefox-desktop

How can I disable/turn it off via Selenium Web Driver? Is there any preference or capability through which I can turn it off in the Firefox profile?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Selenium with PowerShell and I had the same issue.
This solution works for me

```
[OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfileManager]$ProfileManager= [OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfileManager]::new()
[OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile]$FirefoxProfile = $ProfileManager.GetProfile($ProfileName)

$FirefoxProfile.SetPreference("pref.privacy.disable_button.tracking_protection_exceptions", $true)
```

Comment: Is the option really `pref.privacy.disable_button.tracking_protection_exceptions` because it contains "disable_button". The option `pref.privacy.trackingprotection.enabled` sounds more applicable, or?